# Create a doctrine repository class without an entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.1

I'm currently in a situation where I need to create a `Repository` class which would contain multiple financial statistic queries. The queries are not exactly tied up with one `Entity` but rather with multiple `Entities` and will select specific data from the database, based on various some conditions.

Having said that, I'm looking for a way to create a `Repository` class (i.e. `StatisticsRepository`) which is not associated with an `Entity` at all, so I could store the queries there. Simply creating that repository doesn't seem to be working. I'm guessing I probably need to create a service of some kind that loads this repo class? Is this correct, and if so is there an example I'm missing in the Symfony/Doctrine docs?

Comment: You can just create a class that has entity manager injected, create a method(s) that execute your query, and that's all.

Comment: That's what I thought it should be like, but wanted to double check. Please post it as an answer so I could accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a class like `StatisticsService`/`StatisticsFinder` (naming convention is for you).

That service should have an entity manager injected, so define it in your config.
Create a query builder inside that service, then simply get and return results.